# If I have a separate models for an item and a separate model for the images relating to that item, how can I combine these into a query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to display in a card view the items from my queryset. I have a model for Item and a separate model for ItemImage to allow several uploaded images for a single item. Each image also has a property is_primary to determine if it's the image that will be displayed in the dynamically generated cards.

I've succeeded in displaying item details from my item model queryset. However, I am struggling to understand how I can combine the itemimage.url attribute with the all_items context I am passing into the template. How can I make sure that the images from my image queryset match the pk of the item they are assigned to and are also the primary photo for that item?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages 
from .models import Item, ItemImage
    
def home(request):
    all_items = Item.objects.all()
    item_images = ItemImage.objects.all() ItemImage.objects.filter(is_primary=True)
    context = {'items': all_items}
    return render(request,'items/home.html',context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from decimal import Decimal
# Create your models here.

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        

class ItemImage(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content-section d-flex flex-row">
    {% if items%}
        {% for item in items %}
    
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{{item.image_ur}}" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{item.name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{item.description}}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
              </div>
        </div>
        
        
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %} <h2> No items available. </h2>
    {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to fetch the primary `ItemImage`s for each `Item` with:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def home(request):
    all_items = Item.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'itemimage_set',
            ImageItem.objects.filter(is_primary=True)
            to_attr='primary_images'
        )
    )
    context = {'items': all_items}
    return render(request,'items/home.html',context)
```

In your view you can then fetch the primary images related to an `item` with `item.primary_images`, so:

```
<div class="content-section d-flex flex-row">
  {% for item in items %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      {% for img in item.primary_images %}
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ img.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
      {% endfor %}
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{item.name}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.description}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    <h2> No items available. </h2>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

---

> **Note**: Django has a [**`{% for … %} … {% empty %} … {% endfor %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)
> to make rendering a message when a collection is empty more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The prefetch solution worked for me. Another solution I tried is doing a raw query. There's probably a more succinct models based solution but right now the raw SQL is more readable to me.

```
def home(request):
    all_items = Item.objects.raw("SELECT items_item.id, items_item.name, items_item.description, items_item.price, items_item.date_added, items_itemimage.url AS imgurl FROM items_item LEFT JOIN items_itemimage ON items_item.id = items_itemimage.item_id WHERE items_itemimage.is_primary = true ORDER BY date_added DESC")
    context = {'items': all_items}
    return render(request,'items/home.html',context)
```